# Can not upload and display image in webpage with php code

Tags: php

I am facing some problem when I try to upload and display an image with the following php code:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$binary=base64_decode($base);
$file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
?>
```

The image is uploaded and located in the same folder which has the php script.
[image]

Now, if I delete all of the code and replace with just 1 line

```
<?php
    echo "<img src='uploaded_image.jpg' width='500' height='300'/> ";
?>
```

The image which has been uploaded, is displayed in the webpage ok.
Then, I combine both of it (uploading and displaying the image).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
$base=$_REQUEST['image'];
$binary=base64_decode($base);
$file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
fwrite($file, $binary);
fclose($file);
echo "<img src='uploaded_image.jpg' width='500' height='300'/> ";
?>
```

Uet this does not display the image, and it seems that the image has not been uploaded yet.
[image]

What is the problem and how can I solve it? I would like to upload the image and show the image on the webpage.

Comment: can you try to remove the header 
header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8');
and tell whats the result pls

Comment: yes, i try to remove the header header('Content-Type: bitmap; charset=utf-8'); and i upload image ok, but when i refresh web page, size of image is 0. So it still no image every i refresh web page :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no image when you refresh the page because in that case  $base=$_REQUEST['image']; will be empty (when you refresh the page you are not providing it with img upload data.)
So basically it overrides the *uploaded_image.jpg* with empty data.
Just check if you have provided a value for the image. In your case:

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['image'])) {
    $base=$_REQUEST['image'];
    $binary=base64_decode($base);
    $file = fopen('uploaded_image.jpg', 'wb');
    fwrite($file, $binary);
    fclose($file);
}
 echo "<img src='uploaded_image.jpg' width='500' height='300'/> ";
```